# JButton, trying to define states for my button

Tags: java, class, jbutton

I'm trying to define two states for the JButton I've implemented, currently I'm trying to use Button.setEnabled(true); to make sure that JButton is enabled. What I want to achieve is that depending on whether the button is enabled or disabled, I want to give it different color, what I've so far done is:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class MyButton extends JButton {
    Color col1;
    Color col2;
    String text1;
    String text2;
    JButton Button;

public MyButton(Color col1, Color col2, String text1, String text2) {
    this.col1=col1;
    this.col2=col2;
    this.text1=text1;
    this.text2=text2;
    JFrame framen;
    Button=new JButton("Tryck här");
    Button.setEnabled(true);
    Button.setBackground(col1);
    Button.setSize(300,300);
    framen=new JFrame("mybutton testing");
    framen.setSize(700,700);
    framen.setVisible(true);
    framen.add(Button);
}
public MyButton() {
    if (Button.setEnabled(true)) {
    this(Color.red,Color.black,"hej","hej1");}
}

}
```

Due to an assignment I cannot use an actionlistener (yet), is there a way for me to define two states, whether its on or off, 1 or 2, disabled or enabled, etc for my JButton and work from there? I simply cant make setEnabled work for me...